# bootstrap drop downmenu not appear

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web

I currently learn bootstrap and basic web develop thing. but I meet some probleml.

here's code I trying to copy it. 
https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course4/tree/master/examples/Lecture32/after

here's code I currently write. 
https://github.com/KangYUNJAE/cousera-test/tree/gh-pages/mod3

I think it pretty same code but the drop-down menu for small screen seem's not working. what may can be a problem? please help..

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of manually connecting the bootstrap framework you should connect via its cdn

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can check more about setting the bootstrap framework [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Also check if you have any error in your files as well